# How to solve for the values of variables to give the maximum probability of an outcome

Tags: calculus, probability

> A small boy is lost coming down Mount Washington. The leader of the search team estimates that there is a probability p that he came down on the east side and a probability 1 - p that he came down on the west side. He has n people in his search team who will search independently and, if the boy is on the side being searched, each member will fi nd the boy with probability u. Determine how he should divide the n people into two groups to search the two sides of the mountain so that he will have the highest probability of fi nding the boy. How does this depend on u?

I expressed the probability of an individual searching on the right side of the mountain and not finding the boy as $p(1-u)$ and $(1-p)(1-u)$, then raised each term to the number of people searching (n-k on one side and k on the other):

$P(finding\space boy) = 1 - [(p(1-u))^{n-k}+((1-p)(1-u))^k]$

If this is correct, I would need to take the derivative to find the solution.

1) Do I differentiate with respect to u (treating u as a variable and k as a constant), set the derivative to zero, and then solve for k in terms of u and p (which means k is now also a variable?), or do I differentiate with respect to k (I'm not sure how I would go about doing that since it's not a product and I can't take the logarithm)? If the method is the former, I can't wrap my head around how we went from treating k as a constant then as a variable after the differentiation.

2) How do I prove that the k I find is actually a maximum? I assume it would be the second derivative test, if so should I expect a really long and messy equation that (hopefully) simplifies to an expression that must be greater than zero?

Comment: $k$ is your variable, so you must differentiate with respect to $k$.  You can differentiate term by term using, e.g.  $(1-u)^k=\exp(k\ln(1-u))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not get to choose $u$.

$u$ is given to us. What we can do is to determine $k$, the number of manpower to the west side.

First let's discuss the probability of not being found.

He is not found if no one find him, by the law of total probability, the probability that he is not found is

$$p(1-u)^{n-k} + (1-p)(1-u)^{k}$$

Let's differentiate with respect to $k$.

$$-p(1-u)^{n-k}\ln (1-u)+(1-p)(1-u)^k \ln(1-u)=0$$

$$p(1-u)^{n-k}=(1-p)(1-u)^k$$

$$\frac{p}{1-p}=(1-u)^{2k-n}$$

$$\ln \left( \frac{p}{1-p}\right)=(2k-n) \ln (1-u)$$

$$k=\frac{n}{2}+\frac12\frac{\ln \left( \frac{p}{1-p}\right)}{\ln(1-u)}$$

If we compute the second derivative, we have

$$p(1-u)^{n-k}(\ln(1-u))^2+(1-p)(1-u)^k(\ln (1-u))^2 \ge 0$$

Hence that value of $k$ is the value that we want to find it is continuos. For discrete case, we check the boundary values and also the ceiling and the floor function.

Comment: For the first equation, why does the exponent $n-k$ and $k$ not include the $p$ and $(1-p)$? Also could you elaborate more on how to perform the steps in the last statement (regarding the discrete case)?

Comment: P(no one found him) = P(boy goes west)P(no one  found him|west) + P(boy goes east)P(no one  found him|east).  The probability of boy go east and west do not involve exponentiation. The exponentiation part come from the part of probability that he is not found.